# Android - Increment properties in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-analytics, mixpanel

I am adding Firebase Analytics to my Android app to replace Mixpanel. The Mixpanel SDK provides a "set once" people property and it can increment people properties by a given amount. Does Firebase provide anything equivalent to these?